# How say to some behavior attach to all ui elements of some type by defaut?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

For example, I want have all MediaElements in my app that after mouse click on mediaelement leads to play/pause/play/pause... It is possible to say such behavior to attach to all associated elements in app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is straight forward to iterate through all the children of the grid and attach the event appropriately.

In your XAML be sure to give a name for your grid:

```
    <Grid x:Name="gr01"...
```

You can write a function for attaching the events and call that in the `Window_Loaded` event.

```
namespace AttachEventDemo {
   public partial class MainWindow : Window {
      // ... usual initialization code goes here
      private void Window_Loaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
         AttachEvent( );
      }

      private void AttachEvent( ) {
         foreach ( var item in gr01.Children ) {
            switch ( item.GetType( ).ToString( ) ) {
               case "System.Windows.Controls.Button":
                  Button b = item as Button;
                  b.Click += b_Click;
                  txtLog.Text = "Added click event for button " + b.Name + Environment.NewLine + txtLog.Text;
                  break;

               case "System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox":
                  CheckBox cb = item as CheckBox;
                  cb.Checked += cb_Checked;
                  txtLog.Text = "Added click event for checkkbox " + cb.Name + Environment.NewLine + txtLog.Text;
                  break;

               default:
                  break;
            }
         }
      }

      void cb_Checked( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
         CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
         txtLog.Text = "CheckBox " + cb.Name + " checked changed!" + Environment.NewLine + txtLog.Text;
      }

      private void b_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
         Button b = sender as Button;

         txtLog.Text = "Button " + b.Name + " was clicked!" + Environment.NewLine + txtLog.Text;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: hand programmatically way) 10x!